# Problem with initializing AzureOpenAIEmbeddings()

Tags: azure, langchain, py-langchain, openaiembeddings

I get the following error:

> ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call
> last) Cell In[31], line 1
> ----> 1 embeddings = AzureOpenAIEmbeddings(
> 2     azure_endpoint=os.environ["AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT"],
> 3     azure_deployment="text_embedding"
> 4 )
>
> File
> ~/Projects/pia_project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/v1/main.py:341,
> in BaseModel.**init**(**pydantic_self**, **data)
> 339 values, fields_set, validation_error = validate_model(**pydantic_self**.**class**, data)
> 340 if validation_error:
> --> 341     raise validation_error
> 342 try:
> 343     object_setattr(**pydantic_self**, '**dict**', values)
>
> ValidationError: 1 validation error for AzureOpenAIEmbeddings
> **root**   As of openai>=1.0.0, Azure endpoints should be specified via the `azure_endpoint` param not `openai_api_base` (or alias
> `base_url`).  (type=value_error)

Eventhough, executing the following Code

```
from langchain_openai import AzureOpenAIEmbeddings, OpenAIEmbeddings
embeddings = AzureOpenAIEmbeddings(
azure_endpoint=os.environ["AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT"],
azure_deployment="text_embedding"
```

)

The strange thing here is that I use the azure_endpoint parameter, but I still get the error.
I have access to the OpenAi embedding model via Azure that's why I'm using it this way.
How do I solve this issue?

My packages are:
openai                     1.12.0
langchain                  0.1.8
langchain-openai           0.0.6

Comment: i think you have given `base_url` parameter. Recheck the code once again.

Comment: I hope you have referred [AzureOpenAIEmbeddings](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/text_embedding/azureopenai)

Comment: Yes, i used this documentation, but got the error.

Comment: What's the environment that your code is running. Is it vscode?

Comment: yes it is. I use Python 3.9 on a Mac

Answer (score -2):

I am having the same issue, and found the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78162385/having-problems-with-azurechatopenai)

Snapshot of the answer from the link:

> I think you have configured the `OPENAI_API_BASE` environment variable.  It's value will be [automatically taken for `openai_api_base`](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/0ae39ab30ed27072aea938feb65efef74ef4fa4d/libs/partners/openai/langchain_openai/chat_models/azure.py#L122-L123). And that's what the error message(marked in bold) trying to say.